# C# Web Form Calender Return Value to string

Tags: c#, string, forms, calendar

The answer to this is most likely all over the web, and I just can't find it.

I'm writing a C# Web Form, and need to obtain the return value of the calender so that I can convert it to a string (if that is at all possible), however, I have no idea what the return value of it is.

For example: to get the "return value" of a `dateTimePicker` to turn into a string in C# Windows Forms, you simply input `dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();`, however, this should be easier, and yet I can't figure it out.

Thanks for any input in advance!

Comment: Which calendar control are you currently using in your web form?

Comment: Are you after Calender or the DateTimPicker?

Comment: Huge noob to forms here, could you expand on what that means please?

Comment: The Calender return Value as a string is what I'm after

Comment: Maybe post some code, might brighten your question abit.

Comment: It's been answered by anquinas now, but thanks to all of you for taking interest in helping me out here! Great community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the out of the box calendar control:

```
Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is very straightforward:

```
 Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToLongDateString();
```

Adding a reference for posterity: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddate(v=vs.100)

> Use the SelectedDate property to determine the selected date on the
>   Calendar control.
>
> The SelectedDate property and the SelectedDates collection are closely
>   related. When the SelectionMode property is set to
>   CalendarSelectionMode.Day, a mode that allows only a single date
>   selection, SelectedDate and SelectedDates[0] have the same value and
>   SelectedDates.Count equals 1. When the SelectionMode property is set
>   to CalendarSelectionMode.DayWeek or
>   CalendarSelectionMode.DayWeekMonth, modes that allows multiple date
>   selections, SelectedDate and SelectedDates[0] have the same value.
>
> The SelectedDate property is set using a System.DateTime object.
>
> When the user selects a date on the Calendar control, the
>   SelectionChanged event is raised. The SelectedDate property is updated
>   to the selected date. The SelectedDates collection is also updated to
>   contain just this date.

Comment: *sigh* well that was easy enough. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast:

```
DateTime dt = (DateTime)dateTimePicker1.value;
string dtString = dt.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: Sorry If I wasn't clear, I wanted the calender Return value, not the return value of a dateTimePicker.

Thanks anyway, though. I'll keep this code in mind. It will come in handy one day.